# AWS SDK: Start new task and connect it to the service

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I have product on AWS ECS Fargate. I need to write a small console application which will restart task on it remotely.
I wrote small application in C# and I'm using AWS SDK nuggets. My algorithm is:

1. Get VPC arn
2. Create new vpc filter
3. Ger security group arn
4. Get my subnets arn
5. Get latest task definition arn
6. Get current list of run tasks (lets call them "toStop")
7. Start new task
8. Get arn of new task
9. Check status of new task (waiting for "RUNNING")
10. Stop "toStop" tasks

Everything looks work fine but new task is not related to service. New task is starting, it is visible under cluster view but traffic is not switched. After a few seconds service starts new task automatically but it causes connection interrupts.

Code used for start new task looks:

```
        var client = new AmazonECSClient();

        var task = await client.RunTaskAsync(new RunTaskRequest
        {
            Cluster = "My cluster name",
            LaunchType = "FARGATE",
            TaskDefinition = "my task Definition ARN",
            PlatformVersion = "LATEST",
            StartedBy = "User App",

            NetworkConfiguration = new NetworkConfiguration
            {
                AwsvpcConfiguration = new AwsVpcConfiguration
                {
                    Subnets = new List<string>
                    {
                        "my subnet1 arn",
                        "my subnet2 arn",
                        "my subnet3 arn"
                    },
                    SecurityGroups = new List<string>
                    {
                        "my security group arn"
                    },
                }
            }
        });
```

Do I should use different method or nuget? Is it possible to connect new task cluster service? Can it be related to service setting: Desired count - 1?
Only visible difference is Group. Task run by service got name like "service:groupName", my task have group like "family:groupName".

Is possible to connect new task with autobalancer?

Thank you for a help!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how ECS services work. You never call `RunTask` directly on tasks that are part of an ECS service. The ECS service itself manages the tasks. You can't ever associate a task with a service manually. You can't call `RunTask` yourself and then associate that task with the service somehow.

It sounds like you simply need to terminate the currently running task(s) and wait for the ECS service to automatically start new tasks to fulfill the Desired Count setting. Or better yet, call the `UpdateService` API with `forceNewDeployment = true` and ECS will automatically handle running new tasks, waiting for them to be healthy, and then terminating the old tasks.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Thank you- forceNewDeployment that solution what I needed. It helps me a lot.